# Regex and english contractions in strings using Javascript (i'm -> I'm not I'M)

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to select via regex the first character of each word hence \b but try as I might I can't seem to find a way to deal with the case of the single quote ' in words like "I'm" or hyphenated words.

I'd like to be able to do something like this /\b[a-z]/g with a Not \'- etc...

Input: i'm some text
Output: I'm Some Text

Comment: I've updated my answer to account for no Lookbehind.  Hopefully you can use it to achieve what you want.  Sorry for not seeing that you were using Javascript earlier.

Comment: I've added an explanation of the regex and what it is doing, as well as a Javascript demo of how you might use it to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can't use Lookbehinds maybe this will work.  The first capturing group will get any letter followed by a "-" or a "'" character.  The second capturing group will get the first letters of each word like you want.

```
(['-]\b[a-zA-Z])|(\b[a-zA-Z])
```

[Demo Here](https://regex101.com/r/pX1lB6/2)

[Javascript Demo Here](https://jsfiddle.net/tkn9vret/1/)

What's happening with the regex is that there are two capturing groups seperated by an "|" (represents OR).  It will first try to match `(['-]\b[a-zA-Z])` which will grab any letter proceded with a `-` or `'` character.  We gobble this up first, so we can ignore it.

The second capturing group `(\b[a-zA-Z])` is what you actually want.  It will match any letter proceeded by a word boundry.  Since the first capturing group already grabs the characters you don't want we can rest assured that this will grab what you do want and you can act on this group.

Comment: Yes... but sadly JavaScript doesn't support lookbehinds.

Comment: Thanks for the update!  the regexp is evaluated per character? I am having a hard time wrapping my head around regexp really and not being able to do something like, in english this says... and then read it aloud like one can do with code etc

Comment: A buddy managed to come up with this: /(^|\s)[a-z]/g which matches both spaces and the first characters of each word, his originally had \w where I have [a-z] but I thought [a-z] would be a tad quicker as it wouldn't match a-zA-Z0-9 but just a-z. Thoughts?

Comment: @alex Looks like it would work well for what you want.  Just note a couple things.  \s will match any whitespace character so spaces and tabs will be matched (This shouldn't affect what you are doing but you should know what it does).  And a side note about \w  not only will it match alphanumerics, it will also match underscores so it is equivilant to [a-zA-Z0-9_]